# Show that a vector w is a linear combination of the orthogonal vectors u and v

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am currently taking a course in linear algebra and in my course book there is the following example to illustrate a part of the dot product:

Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are two orthogonal vectors with the length 3 and 4 respectively. Further, suppose that a vector $w$ exists in the same plane as $u$ and $v$. Prove that $w$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.

Solution: because the vector $w$ is in the same plane as $u$ and $v$, it can therefor be written as a linear combination $w=xu+yv$. The dot product of this equation, using $u$, yields: $u\cdot w=x(u\cdot u) + y(u \cdot v)=x|u|^2+0=9x$. This results in $x = \frac{u\cdot w}{9}$.

Multiply instead with $v$ and we get $v\cdot w=x(v\cdot u)+y(v\cdot v)=0+y|v|^2=16y$. Which yields $y=\frac{v\cdot w}{16}$

I get the equation and calculations but what I do not understand is:

(1) *how does this actually work?*

(2) Whenever I try to multiply equations on tests in order to derive new expressions of the same equation and then put it back in, I always get something like 1 = 1. *Why is the result here not 1 = 1?*

(3) ***How would I, as an aspiring mathematician and new to linear algebra come up with this myself?***

Comment: What definition do you have for "$w$ is in the same plane as $u$ and $v$"? To my ears, that's equivalent to "$w=au+bv$ for some $a,b$ and so the question is a tautology. (Finding $a,b$ isn't, but them existing is.)

Comment: I take your second question to effectively be asking: If $u,v$ are of the prescribed form, how does one see that $$w=\frac{w\cdot u}{9}u+\frac{w\cdot v}{16}v$$ is valid regardless of $w$?

Comment: @Semiclassical what do you mean? The very equivalence you describe is described in my question. What I am asking is: How is it that multiplying the whole equation with $u$ and $v$ and then deriving what $x$ and $y$ is, putting the results back in the equation does not result in 1 = 1? I believe that question is best asked by the bold question in my post: how does one come to think of this? What does this actually mean and how does one prove that the equation is not 1 = 1? I ask because when I do things like this during tests I always end up with 1 = 1, useless info. Yes that is my question!